# Converting SQL Table into Entity for ASP.Net EF 5 Code First

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, asp.net-4.5

I am trying to convert an older website to use ASP.Net 4.5 and EF5 Code First but there is one table from the old site I can not figure out how to convert since it has two columns that both referance the same column in it's parent table. Can anyone help me convert this table?

```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.tblCollectionsList
    (
        ListID smallint IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL,
        SectionID smallint NOT NULL,
        IncludedSectionID smallint NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT PK_CollectionsList_ListID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ListID ASC),
        CONSTRAINT FK_CollectionList_SectionInfo FOREIGN KEY (SectionID) REFERENCES dbo.tblSectionInfo (SectionID),
        CONSTRAINT FK_CollectionList_SectionInfo2 FOREIGN KEY (IncludedSectionID) REFERENCES dbo.tblSectionInfo (SectionID)
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excuse the personal preference for table names, but the issue you face is with cascading deletes, you can turn this behavior off in the model creation:

```
[Table("Section")]
public class Section
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}

[Table("List")]
public class List
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Section")]
    public virtual int SectionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Section Section { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("IncludedSection")]
    public virtual int IncludedSectionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Section IncludedSection { get; set; }
}

public class SectionContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();   
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
    public DbSet<Section> Sections { get; set; }
    public DbSet<List> Lists { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: how will disabing this effect other tables and deletes? Will this also present any issues with Automatic Migrations?

Comment: As long as you do not rely on cascading deletes, which as a personal strategy I do not recommend leveraging anyways, it will not present any issues.  I only use Automatic Migrations in development/integration environments so this has not presented any issues since the data is not normally equivalent to production. (To clarify, in a large system its better to take your development environment and script your changes into files for your deployment to production with 3rd party tools, tested in staging, rather than relying on automigrations.)

Answer (score 0):

This is it using Attributes, you could also do the same thing without the attributes and instead use the FluentApi in `OnModelCreating`.

```
[Table("tblCollectionsList")]
public class CollectionsList
{
[Key]
public byte ListID {get;set;}
public byte SectionID {get;set;}
public byte IncludedSectionID {get;set;}

[ForeignKey("SectionID")]
public virtual Section Section {get;set;}
[ForeignKey("IncludedSectionID")]
public virtual Section IncludedSection {get;set;}

}
```

Comment: I actualy already tried that but got the error: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.CollectionItem_dbo.Section_IncludedSectionID' on table 'CollectionItem' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.